# Vue.js component method "not defined on the instance"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning vue.js and used vue-cli to setup a new project. Now I tried adding a method to a component but something is wrong:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="task in $state.settings.subtasks">
        <input type="text" v-model="task.text">
        <input type="text" v-model="task.assignedTo">
        <input type="button" v-on:click="removeTask(task)">
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'settings',
  methods:{
    removeTask:function(task){
       console.log("remove task");
    } 
  }
}
```

Clicking the button should call the removeTask function but it just outputs an error in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "removeTask" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Settings> at src/views/Settings.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When I went back to my question I noticed I was missing the `</script>` end tag. Adding that solved my problem.